# Sql Closest 2 Days to Today

Tags: sql-server, date, closest, getdate

I have a `Product` table and I join it with `OrderTracking` table

## Product

- ProductCode
- ProductName
- ManufacturerCode
- Price
- Etc...

## OrderTracking

- ProductCode
- OrderID
- Ammount
- DeliveryDate
- ShippingNumber
- Etc...

---

```
SELECT Product.ProductCode,

 FROM Product LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderTracking
    ON Product.ProductCode=OrderTracking.ProductCode

 GROUP BY ProductCode
```

There are past and future order infos of products in my OrderTracking table.
My goal is If there are future orders of a product I want to list first 2 of them(closest 2 orders to today) in same row. If there is no order in the future, columns will be null or if there is just one order in future, just second column will be null. Example row will be like that:

- ProductCode
- 1stClosestDeliveryDate
- 1stClosestOrderAmount
- 1stShippingNumber
- 2ndClosestDeliveryDate
- 2ndClosestOrderAmount
- 2ndShippingNumber

  ```
     SELECT Product.ProductCode, 1stClosestDeliveryDate,1tClosestOrderAmount,
       1stShippingNumber,2stClosestOrderDate, 2stClosestDeliveryAmount,  
     2stShippingNumber
     FROM Product LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderTracking 
     ON Product.ProductCode = OrderTracking.ProductCode
     GROUP BY Product.ProductCode
  ```

  I should use `GETDATE()` function and compare with other date values but I couldn't figure out how to get these values from OrderTracking table. Any help will be appreciate...

Comment: Can you add the structure of your tables ? More specifically OrderTracking table ?

Comment: ok, Im editing again with table structures @Horia

Comment: which column do you want to be nearest getdate() ? Please prefix your columns.

Comment: DeliveryDate will be compared with GETDATE()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a [`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH orders AS
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY OrderDate ASC) AS RNumber
       , ProductCode
       , OrderDate
       , OrderAmount
       , OrderShippingNumber
 FROM OrderTracking
 WHERE OrderDate > GETDATE()
)
SELECT Product.ProductCode
       , 1stClosestOrderDate = O1.OrderDate
       , 1tClosestOrderAmount = O1.OrderAmount
       , 1stShippingNumber = O1.OrderShippingNumber
       , 2stClosestOrderDate = O2.OrderDate
       , 2stClosestOrderAmount = O2.OrderAmount
       , 2stShippingNumber = O2.OrderShippingNumber
FROM Product
       LEFT OUTER JOIN orders AS O1 ON Product.ProductCode = O1.ProductCode AND O1.RNumber = 1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN orders AS O2 ON Product.ProductCode = O2.ProductCode AND O2.RNumber = 2;
```

in the structure you post there is some column missing so i guessed some name but the above should be a starting point to get the final result.

the first `SELECT` (the `CTE`) gathers the data about the orders adding row numbers by product: rows with row number = 1 are the next order for that product and rows with number = 2 are the second next order.

the second `SELECT` is there to join table & `CTE` to get the required output.

**WARNING**: the `CTE` syntax requires that the previous statement (if any) is terminated by a `;`. since the closing semicolon is not mandatory it's easy to forget it and get syntax errors when running the whole statement in a script with multiple statements.

Comment: first select sentence bring me row numbers and other values I need but second select gives syntax error when i implement it to my query. Actually I have never used WITH in my queries so I couldnt figure out that part

Comment: can you give more information what does second select do? @Paolo

Comment: the second select is THE select. the order's data is gathered by the 1st select and made available to the following statement by a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx); with the 2nd select you join the product with the rows having nr = 1 to get 1st next order and rows with nr = 2 to get 2nd next.

Comment: I still get syntax error :( I dont know whats wrong on my implementation... @Paolo

Comment: Finally I implement it gently and it worked. That really helped me dude, Thank you.